# " Object java.lang.String not a value" error in scala code

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I have the below piece of code in my scala program that uses Flink's Table API.

```
val custTS = new CsvTableSource("D:\\input\\customerinfo.csv", 
                               Array("customerId","name","address","zip"),
                               Array(String,String,String,Long))
```

The editor is displaying error at the third line for the three 'String's with the error message "Object java.lang.String not a value". 'String' is used in many other places in the rest of the code. But it doesn't throw error anywhere else. I saw a couple of Stackoverflow questions with similar issues mentioned, but I couldn't fix this based on the solutions mentioned. 
The imports in the program are given below.

```
import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.table.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.table.sinks.CsvTableSink
import org.apache.flink.table.sources.CsvTableSource
```

I have used 'String' in many other scala programs for Flink. But I haven't encountered such an error in any of those programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can't use types (in this case `String`) as a value in `Array`. Collections stores objects. You should pass array of type `Array[TypeInformation[_]]`.

So it should look like:

```
import org.apache.flink.table.api.Types

val custTS = new CsvTableSource(
  "D:\\input\\customerinfo.csv",
  Array("customerId", "name", "address", "zip"),
  Array[TypeInformation[_]](Types.STRING, Types.STRING, Types.STRING, Types.LONG)
  )
```

Unfortunately right now you have to explicitly provide type for the `Array`. For reasons why, you can have a look at [this](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Compiler-error-while-using-CsvTableSource-td11412.html) discussion.

Comment: Thank you Dawid. That solved the problem. In the previous code, I had used the code snippet from the link "https://www.slideshare.net/fhueske/taking-a-look-under-hood-of-apache-flinks-relational-apis" as my reference. 
But I guess they were supposed to be guidelines and not to be used directly in the code.